Is there any dielectric material whose dielectric constant varies with applied time varying electric or magnetic field?
I want to achieve UWB communication over light in free space. Naturally, frequency modulation of light comes to mind. Can we do that? How?
My mind says yes. But has anybody tried this?
Is Lithium Neobate a bait or actually workable? If yes, why don't we see in action in any product?
Bottomline is can we have cellphone to cellphone UWB communication over light in free space?

LiNbO is used in various optical transmitter and receiver devices. Many semiconductors also have substantial electro-optic effect (but usually also high attenuation to make designing with them more difficult).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
